# Most appropriate language to create a Windows application that can serially communicate with hardware via USB and Bluetooth?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, serial-port, usb

So I need to create a PC application, that can serially communicate via USB and Bluetooth to a hardware device.

EDIT: This device is being made by the company I work for and I will be working hand in hand with embedded programmer who will take care of software on the device. My only real concern is creating an interface on the PC and sending that information serially by either means to this device.

The vast majority of the application will stay the same including the serial data, the only difference being the type of communication.

I have a fair amount of experience in Java, some C/C++ and significantly more experience in Android.

I was thinking C# for the ease of GUI and it's .NET capabilities.

Any suggestions based on knowledge or experience would be appreciated.

Thanks

PS. Any information on how Bluetooth protocols vary between different PCs would also be very helpful

Comment: If you might want to get your project working on Linux and Mac OS X, you should avoid C# and .NET because there is no good cross-platform way to make GUI in .NET.  I would instead use Qt and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various suppliers of Bluetooth software for Windows: Microsoft, Broadcom/Widcomm, BlueSoleil, etc. They can each generally use any USB dongle.

Another good reason to go with .NET is that you can use my Bluetooth library which supports all of those stacks and more. :-)  http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Connect with BluetoothClient etc. e.g. [32feet.NET docs -- General Bluetooth Data Connections](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=General%20Bluetooth%20Data%20Connections)

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly this with Serial over Bluetooth using an Arduino microcontroller. I used C# for interfacing with the micro, and XNA for displaying information (3D graphing).

Couldn't recommend it more as an approach, C# is really easy to use for serial.

Take a look at [Visualising Serial Data: Arduino, I2C and XNA](http://capnfabs.net/blog/2011/10/14/visualising-serial-data-arduino-i2c-xna-and-more-tlas-than-are-worth-it-imo/) for detailed instructions.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the insight, involves fair amount of what I need to be doing - cheers

Comment: XNA is quite complicated for visualisation, but if you just need simple displays you can whip them up with WPF.

Comment: WPF is for 3d graphics rendering right? If so, no real need for that.

Comment: No, WPF is for 2D. It's simple and powerful for GUIs.